# PulseAudio: `module-alsa-sink` cannot be loaded automatically by `module-udev-detect`

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

In short, on my machine,

1. The card profile `Analog Stereo Output` and `Analog Stereo Duplex` are shown `available: no` (both from `pactl list cards` and the PulseAudio Volume Control GUI)
2. When I boot Ubuntu 20.04, the Sound Ouput only has a Dummy Output option. So does `pactl list sinks` (detailed below).
3. I can do a dirty fix by either `pactl load-module module-detect` or `pactl load-module module-alsa-sink`. In other words, once I run either of them, I got the sink shown from `pactl list sinks`.
4. Even I do 3, the card profiles are still not available.
5. I don't know if this is a driver problem, but even I manually fix the problem, the sound is sometimes unstable. Every time I open a sound-related app I hear "bzzz".

I only have the onboard sound card in my Intel NUC10i7107FNH. And I just use a headphone jack plugged in.

So my question is why this happens? It seems my hardware and drivers have no problems.

Why `module-udev-detect` does not do its job (according to PulseAudio [doc](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/#module-detect), `module-udev-detect` is the primary one to handle everything, not `module-detect`, and we should not manually call `module-alsa-sinks`). How to fix it?

### Linux version

Notice this is a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop. Every configuration of ALSA and PulseAudio is in the default state.

```
5.8.0-43-generic #49~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 5 09:57:56 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

### Sound card info and codec

```
$ cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0x6023110000 irq 178
```

```
$ cat /proc/asound/card0/codec\#0 | grep Codec
Codec: Realtek ALC256
```

### List modules

```
$ lsmod | grep snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_intel          53248  2
snd_intel_dspcfg       24576  3 snd_hda_intel,snd_sof_pci,snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_hda_codec         139264  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_soc_hdac_hda
snd_hda_core           94208  9 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_pcm               114688  9 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_hda_core,snd_pcm_dmaengine
snd                    94208  17 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
```

### Output from `pactl list cards`

```
>>= pactl list cards
Card #0
    Name: alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3
    Driver: module-alsa-card.c
    Owner Module: 7
    Properties:
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0x6023110000 irq 178"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "02c8"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "0"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    Profiles:
        input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 0, sources: 1, priority: 65, available: yes)
        output:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 6500, available: no)
        output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Duplex (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 6565, available: no)
...
...
...
```

### Output from `pactl list sinks`

```
$ pactl list sinks                                 
Sink #0
    State: SUSPENDED
    Name: auto_null
    Description: Dummy Output
    Driver: module-null-sink.c
    Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right
    Owner Module: 14
    Mute: no
    Volume: front-left: 11097 /  17% / -46.28 dB,   front-right: 11097 /  17% / -46.28 dB
            balance 0.00
    Base Volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    Monitor Source: auto_null.monitor
    Latency: 0 usec, configured 0 usec
    Flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY SET_FORMATS 
    Properties:
        device.description = "Dummy Output"
        device.class = "abstract"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card"
    Formats:
        pcm
```

Try to fix:

```
$ pactl load-module module-alsa-sink 
24

$ pactl list sinks                  
Sink #1
    State: IDLE
    Name: alsa_output.default
    Description: Built-in Audio
    Driver: module-alsa-sink.c
    Sample Specification: s32le 2ch 48000Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right
    Owner Module: 24
    Mute: no
    Volume: front-left: 45876 /  70% / -9.29 dB,   front-right: 45876 /  70% / -9.29 dB
            balance 0.00
    Base Volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    Monitor Source: alsa_output.default.monitor
    Latency: 242825 usec, configured 341333 usec
    Flags: HARDWARE DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
    Properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "32"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "ALC256 Analog"
        alsa.id = "ALC256 Analog"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0x6023110000 irq 178"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "02c8"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "default"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "131072"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "8192"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    Formats:
        pcm
```

Comment: same almost problem here except bzzzz after upgrade... using `pactl load-module module-detect` to restore sound. `journalctl -xe --user-unit pulseaudio` procudes some interesting errors. "sudo alsa force-reload" failed to me while was workign after upgrade. `systemctl --user restart pulseaudio` makes "no output device found"!!! errors: `pulseaudio[110879]: module-detect is deprecated: Please use module-udev-detect instead of module-detect!
pulseaudio[110879]: Failed to load module "module-alsa-sink" (argument: "device_id=0"): initialization failed.`